# how to disable "warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion" without modifying sources

Tags: java, ant

I get the "warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion" message in a library whose sources I am compiling alongside my code. Since I don't want to modify the library sources, is there a way to disable that particular warning in Ant's `javac` task?

Answer (score 4):

The `unchecked` Xlint option *cannot be disabled*, at least not using an `-Xlink:-unchecked` javac flag.

This appears to be enforced in the `com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check` class of the compiler, see line 127 of [this version](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/langtools/file/86e0dad6aadf/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/comp/Check.java#l127) from the `jdk8-b40` tag (excerpt below).

```
    boolean verboseDeprecated = lint.isEnabled(LintCategory.DEPRECATION);
    boolean verboseUnchecked = lint.isEnabled(LintCategory.UNCHECKED);
    boolean verboseSunApi = lint.isEnabled(LintCategory.SUNAPI);
    boolean enforceMandatoryWarnings = source.enforceMandatoryWarnings();

    deprecationHandler = new MandatoryWarningHandler(log, verboseDeprecated,
            enforceMandatoryWarnings, "deprecated", LintCategory.DEPRECATION);
    uncheckedHandler = new MandatoryWarningHandler(log, verboseUnchecked,
            enforceMandatoryWarnings, "unchecked", LintCategory.UNCHECKED);
    sunApiHandler = new MandatoryWarningHandler(log, verboseSunApi,
            enforceMandatoryWarnings, "sunapi", null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try the javac option `-Xlint:-name` where *name* is the name of a warning to disable. The list of possible names is given [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#xlintwarnings). So I guess in your case, the name would be "unchecked".

In an Ant script, this would look like:

```
<javac ...>
  <compilerarg value="-Xlint:-unchecked"/>
  ...
</javac>
```

Comment: Passing `-Xlint:-unchecked` to the compiler does not work. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30636410/1951001).

Comment: To get rid of `warning: [unchecked] unchecked conversion` and instead get `Note: ... uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.` You can just remove `-Xlint:unchecked` as @TimothyMcCarthy mentioned, `-Xlint:-unchecked` does nothing.  The docs description for the option is "Give more detail for unchecked conversion warnings that are **mandated** by the Java Language Specification."

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
<javac classpathref="project.class.path">
   nowarn="true"
   deprecation="false"
   ....
</javac>
```

Comment: I am trying to disable **that particular** warning.

Comment: Ah! I don't think there's a way to disable that specific warning without annotating it or disabling all the other warnings. If you aren't going to modify the library source, the only workaround otherwise that I can think of would be to compile the library into a jar, and then simply linking against that jar. Or compile everything with two distinct javac tasks, one for the library, and one for the rest.